# A-Frame AR: Is there a way to place the 3D Object directly on top of the marker once detected?

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

I'm working on a project for an exhibition and I'm trying to use the AR experience on top of some paintings.

I tried to use a-image and a-nft but I have a lot of issues on place the AR object exactly on top of the illustration. Not sure if it's actually feasible but it would be great to have it at least that is more or less on top.

Is there any snippet with JS that can help to achieve this?

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Personally i had more consistent results with MindAR ( for `a-frame` ), did you try it out?

Comment: nope, I never heard that but I will def check that out! thank you so much (:

Comment: [check it out](https://hiukim.github.io/mind-ar-js-doc/examples/minimal), i have an some examples with models / video [here](https://github.com/gftruj/webzamples/tree/master/ar)